# How to make a redirection that fired a script before redirecting?

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-analytics

I have a software that I must host in an external server in a niche market (kind of extensions for browsers). I want to know how many people click on the link when I share it on social media.

My idea is to redirect a post in my site to it, but before the redirection happens the Google Analytics script should be fired, so that I get the report. The [Redirection](https://github.com/johngodley/redirection/issues/477) plugin can be used for redirection, but [it doesn't support that yet](https://github.com/johngodley/redirection/issues/477). One go-around idea is to create a post and add this:

```
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

but it may increase the loading time for loading the header. Plus that it doesn't guarantee that the script will be fired, as it can be included at the footer.

Is there a way to make sure that the script is fired before redirection?

Comment: In order to answer this question properly, a lot more information would need to be known about the real "why" you're trying to do this. It is never a good idea to use JS to perform a redirect, and the situation you described as having a URL on your site only exist to redirect to an external site has some potential ethical implications. I can think of only a few legitimate scenarios where you would want to redirect the traffic to an external site and capture the traffic in your analytics. The first question would be, do you control the external site?

Comment: Technically yes. The content of the specific page I'm trying to redirect at is mine. Would that be OK? And even if it's not, then why would it be an ethical issue?

Comment: If you control the external site then remove your JS redirect, perform the redirect properly on the server side as a 301 or 302, and add your necessary analytics code to the target page to track the referrer. Otherwise, it isn't your content or really your traffic, and your URL is never going to be indexed for that content anyway.

Comment: Say I post a clip on YouTube. Do you mean that even if I track the redirection, I will never get a complete report on the traffic on that clip? Why wouldn't that clip be my content? I see that that this is just a simple outbound-tracking case?

Comment: See, this is why I said you need to start with the first question "why am I doing this", that's the first step to finding the right solution. I don't know why you would want to create a post/url, just to redirect it to your youtube video. Technically, yes it's your video, it's also technically YouTube's content. Google is not ever going to index your url over YouTube's, yours only contains a small bit of JS, nothing else. They might even penalize your site for doing that. Why not just make it an actual page and embed the video?

Comment: well, it's actually not a video, but a software that I must host in an external server in a niche market (kind of extensions for browsers). So I cannot embed it but just a link. All I want is to put it on social media and be able to know how many people click on it.

Comment: There's still infinitely better options available than creating what is effectively a null page just to perform a JS redirect to the actual content in order to capture that pass through in GA. Why not create an actual page that provides more information, describes your software and what it does and why people should use it, then include a downlaod button that goes to the 3rd party URL? That way you actually have valuable content that you can get indexed for and it makes sense to send the user to your URL? You could also track the clicks server side and then 301 redirect properly.

Comment: I do have a detailed description of that product, but it is written in English, and my website is for Vietnamese readers only. I can copy the text to my website nevertheless, but the users would need to read the it twice before about to download it. I just want to save their time as much as possible. // "You could also track the clicks server side and then 301 redirect properly." → This is what I have described in the question: I want to send the information to my Google Analytics account

Answer (score 0):

Place both scripts in the footer. In order, put Google scripts first, wrap in a promise, then add:

```
   .then(
      function(response){
         window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; //for example
      },function(error){
        console.log('Error: ' + error.statusText);
       }
    );
```

Comment: but then this would fire all things in the header and body? Doesn't this not reduce the loading time?

Comment: Everything in the header and body would be fired, but that's also necessary if you want real analytics from Google. If you're simply looking for the hit count, then you could fire it in the header.

Comment: yes, for the time being I just need hit count. What do you mean by "real analytics"?

Comment: If you fire in the header, you'll miss out on any session information or demographic info. But that's not a big deal given your application.

Comment: wait. Those metrics can only be counted when the body is fired? How strange! I thought all you need is just having the script fired?

Comment: A rudimentary amount of information will present, but there is an amount of time and interaction necessary for all metrics to be displayed.